# R desolve number of Derivatives error, but matching number of differential equations and

Tags: r

The error R stuido gives us is:
Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) : The number of derivatives returned by func() (9) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (10)

However the number of functions *does* match the number of initial conditions and its driving us nuts.

We have tried removing an initial condition and the program works... but the solutions don't make any sense.  We think we might have syntax error that went rogue and is causing this error, but since all the people working on this project are novice to R, we can't accurately diagnose the problem. For context we are solving Differential Algebraic Equations of index 2, which cannot be done on our student license of MATLAB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code in question is below:

```
library("deSolve")

DAEFUNC <- function(t, y, dy, parms) {
  with (as.list(c(y, dy, parms1)), {
    f1 <- y[0]*cv1*dy[6]-R*y[6]*dy[1]
    f2 <- (dy[1]+dy[4])*cv2*y[7] + cv2*dy[7]*dy[2]-dy[5]-P2*dy[9]-dy[1]*y[6]*(cv1+R)-dy[4]*T3*(cv3+R)
    f3 <- -dy[5]+P3*dy[10]+dy[4]*cv3*T3-mdot3*P3*nu3-dy[4]*y[7]*(cv3+R)
    f4 <- dy[5]-h*A*(y[7]-T3)
    f5 <- dy[4] - dy[5]/Hv
    f6 <- dy[9]-mdot3/rho3
    f7 <- y[8]*V1-y[1]*R*y[6]
    f8 <- P2*y[9]-y[2]*R*y[7]
    f9 <- dy[2]-dy[1]-dy[4]
    f10 <- dy[3]+mdot3+dy[4]

   list(c(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10))
  })
}

times <- seq(0, 38, 0.1)


for (M1_0 in seq(0, 45, 1)) {
  for(P1_0 in seq(0, 35000000, 10)){
    R <- 8.314
    T1_0 <- 23+273.15; #roome temp kelvin
    V1_0 <- M1_0*R*T1_0/P1_0; #ideal gas law for He
    parms <- c(cv1 = 3.15, cv2 = 3.15, cv3 = 0.4, R = 8.314, P2 = 25.85, P3 = 25.85, h = 0.0126,
              A = 0.2794, T3 = 90.19, mdot3 =3.760, Hv = 213, nu3 = 1/1141, rho3 = 1141, V1=V1_0)

    yini <- c(M1_0,0,127.786,0,0,298,298,P1_0,0.01119981,0.1007983)

    out <- radau (y = yini, func = DAEFUNC, parms = parms, times = times)
    if(~class(out)== "complex"){
      plot(out, which = 1:4, type = "l", lwd = 2)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but note from the documentation `If func is an R-function, it must be defined as:
func <-function(t,y,parms,...).` So you may want to try writing your function as `function(t, y, parms, dy)`

Comment: Yes, it is function(t, y, parms, ...) The names of the first 3 arguments do not matter, but the order does for efficiency reasons. I tried to reproduce the example, but it does not work.

- "parms1" may be "parms"
- what is "dy"?
- as far as I remember, raday cannot work with complex, but yiu can use zvode instead. 
- if the number of returned values does not match, it may be a result of vectorization, i.e. one of the return vatiables (f1 ... f10) may be a vector of length !=1

what is "dy" in your function?